# Why does \s* match a string with just whitespace but [[:blank:]] does not?

Tags: regex

When debugging why a regex was not matching a specific line that only contains white space, I noticed this odd case.  Using Powershell:

```
PS G:\> ([Regex]'^\s*$').IsMatch("")
True

PS G:\> ([Regex]'^[[:Blank:]]*$').IsMatch("")
True

PS G:\> ([Regex]'^\s*$').IsMatch(" ")
True

PS G:\> ([Regex]'^[[:Blank:]]*$').IsMatch(" ")
False
```

Why does the last line using [[:Blank:]] and matching " " not return true?

I know that unlike \s, [[:Blank:]] only matches spaces and tabs, but the final line shown above is just spaces.  Does this have something to do with the string terminus being part of the " ", but not part of the special "" (Empty string)?

Comment: *.NET Regexes don't support the Posix character classes. They do however support Unicode groups.* To only match horizontal whitespace in .NET, use `[\p{Zs}\t]` instead of `[[:blank:]]`

Comment: Ah, yes that would explain it, thanks!